# $f $ Borel measurable $\iff f^+, f^-$ are both Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f= f^+-f^-$. Show that $f$ is Borel measurable if and only if $f^+, f^-$ are both Borel measurable.

Attempt:

Suppose that $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both Borel measurable. Then their difference $f^+-f^-$ is also Borel measurable because the difference of two Borel measurable functions $a(x),b(x)$ is Borel measurable because $\{a(x)>\alpha+b(x)\}$ can be written as a union of Borel measurable sets.

For the other direction, I'm not sure where to start. I thought of trying to rewrite $f=f^+-f^-$ as the difference of two Borel measurable functions again, but of course we don't know that either $f^+, f^-$ are Borel measurable. A hint to get started would be welcomed. Thanks.

(By the way, $f^+, f^-$ is notation used in lattices, where $f^-=-(f\wedge 0)$ and $f^+=f \vee 0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U_a = (a, \infty)$.  We note that
$$
(f^+)^{-1}(U_a) = \\
\{f^+(x) > a\} = \\
\{\max\{f(x),0\} > a \}
$$
this gives us $f^{-1}(U_a)$ when $a \geq 0$ and $\Bbb R$ otherwise.  In either case, we conclude $(f^+)^{-1}(U_a)$ is Borel.

The proof for $f^-$ is similar.

Comment: Just to make sure, for $f^-$, we'd have $\{f^-(x)\geq \alpha\}=\{\min\{f,0\}\geq \alpha\}$?

Comment: Not exactly; by definition, it should be
$$
\{f^-(x) \geq \alpha\} = 
\{-\min\{f,0\}\geq \alpha\} = 
\{\min\{f,0\} \leq -\alpha\}
$$

Comment: Ah, ok. That's because $\max\{f,g\}=-\min\{f,g\}.$ Thanks.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan that statement is not correct

Comment: Oops. I am mixing up definitions. Thanks for the clarifications.